# Order generation plugin

Tags: orders

I need to create 200-300k orders with bogus information so that I can test some functionality of a Magento Connect module that I am creating. I need the purchased products to be products from my store, with registered customers from my store.

I have yet to find a tool to create orders en-masse. Any pointers would be welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't overly complex to [programatically create orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877767/create-order-programmatically-in-magento) via the PHP API.

Otherwise, if it is important to replicate the order process as if a customer were really doing it - then make a profile with something like Apache jMeter. We use jMeter to load test clusters - and have built profiles to replicate the entire purchase process - click for click (including the Ajax fires in the OPC).

Is it important for you to test its functionality with a DB full of orders - or test the functionality under the load of orders being created.

Comment: +1 for Apache jMeter - what an awesome tool. The requirement was fulfilled by creating Selenium test cases and letting them run for a couple of days. I will definitely look into jMeter, though.